# Como obter os valores de uma lista de inputs com mesmo ID por WebForms?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

Tenho uma lista de inputs que são gerados automaticamente por script e eles são inseridos em um formulário ficando dessa forma:

```
<input type="text" id="txtValue" name="txtValue" />
<input type="text" id="txtValue" name="txtValue" />
<input type="text" id="txtValue" name="txtValue" />
...
```

Não trata-se de elementos manipulados pelo code-behind do C# (aplicação Asp.NET WenForms), e preciso obter esses valores em back-end ao efetuar o post do formulário.

Como então capturar esses valores?
É possível, por exemplo, trabalhar com esses valores em forma de um vetor?

**Obs**: Ao analisar o `Request.Form` eu verifiquei que apenas um elemento txtValue aparecia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obter os valores mesmo em inputs com mesmo Id é muito simples. Nesse tipo de caso o asp.net WebForms vai disponibilizar o conteúdo de cada elemento em uma string única onde os valores estarão separados por vírgula.

**Exemplo: 101, 104, 300 ...**

Para obter os valores então eu fiz o seguinte:

```
var values = Request.Form["txtValue"].Split(',');
```

Os valores seguem a ordem de criação segundo os nodes, e os inputs que não receberem valores virão na lista como espaços em branco, facilitando então saber quais receberam e quais não receberam valores.

**Exemplo: 101, , 300, 400 ...**

Veja que nesse segundo exemplo, após o valor 101 temos duas vírgulas uma após a outra.
Isso geraria um vetor como:

```
values[0] --> "101"
values[1] --> ""
values[2] --> "300"
values[3] --> "400"
```

Comment: Sua resposta está correta porém é um erro ter mais de um elemento com o mesmo `id`, o `id` de um elemento deve ser único na página, para esses casos onde se precisa de vários campos com o mesmo nome deve-se usar o atributo `name` do `input`

Comment: Neste caso pode, já que ele não me parece ser usado para nada, simplesmente trocando de `id` para `name` resolve o problema, o `Request.Form["txtValue"]` deve funcionar normalmente, e inclusive em testes que fiz aqui usando apenas o `id` eu não consegui pegar os valores, só quando troquei para `name` que funcionou, e eu testei no IE, Chrome, FireFox e Opera 12 tendo o mesmo resultado em todos